# configure colors for nestjs logger

Tags: nestjs

Is it possible to configure colors [nestjs uses for logging](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger)? I see that `NO_COLOR` env variable might be provided to disable them, but no documentation on how to configure them.

[image: colors example]

Comment: I think you should create a service like customLogger class extend Logger. Override LoggerService to set custom colors and use ASCII to change the color

Comment: Solution, but sounds like a bit overkill to implement whole logger just for colors change